# Overflow-x hidden causing responsive nav menu positing issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Question Background:**

I am using Jasny Bootstrap to implement a responsive offcanvas 'reveal' style menu.

**The Issue:**

When the menu is opened on a mobile device the scrolling element of the menu is not enabling.

I have wrapped the entire app (where my AngularJS view is injected) with a div style `overflow-y:hidden` as shown:

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div style="overflow-x:hidden">
        <div ui-view style="height:100%">
            //View is injected here based on routing.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This overflow styling means i can now scroll the menu on a mobile device but i now have an issue where and When the menu is scrolled to the top there is a gap showing the menu underneath as shown here:

[image]

Once the page is scrolled down slightly the responsive navbar shows:

[image]

**The Code:**

The Following is as shown above, This is the main View div where the page is injected depending on its routing:

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div style="overflow-x:hidden">
        <div ui-view style="height:100%">
            //View is injected here based on routing.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is the Results view of the app which contains the navbar elements:

```
<div ng-controller="ResultsController" ng-show="hideSearch" style="height:100%">
    <div class="navmenu navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-left" id="updateMenu">
        <div class="text-center headerPad"><h3>Compzee <img src="Images/CompzeeLogoSmall.png" class="logoSize" /></h3></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 pullInMenu">
            <form ng-submit="search()" novalidate="novalidate">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="search">Search Term:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="item" id="itemUpdate" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="search">Product Category:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="catagory" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select A Product Category</option>
                        <option>All</option>
                        <option>Baby</option>
                        <option>Business, Office &amp; Industrial</option>
                        <option>Cameras &amp; Photography</option>
                        <option>Clothes &amp; Accessories</option>
                        <option>Comics, Books &amp; Magazines</option>
                        <option>Computers &amp; Tablets</option>
                        <option>Consoles</option>
                        <option>DVD's, Films &amp; TV</option>
                        <option>Garden &amp; Patio</option>
                        <option>Health &amp; Beauty</option>
                        <option>Holiday &amp; Travel</option>
                        <option>Home</option>
                        <option>Kitchen</option>
                        <option>Jewellery</option>
                        <option>Mobile Phones &amp; Accessories</option>
                        <option>Musical Instruments</option>
                        <option>Music</option>
                        <option>Pet Supplies</option>
                        <option>Shoes</option>
                        <option>Sporting Goods</option>
                        <option>Toys &amp; Games</option>
                        <option>Vehicle Parts &amp; Accessories</option>
                        <option>Video Games</option>
                        <option>Watches</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="search">Country:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedCountry" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select A Country</option>
                        <option>UK</option>
                        <option>US</option>
                        <option>FR</option>
                        <option>DE</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <img ng-src="{{countryImg}}" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="search">Marketplace</label>
                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedMarketPlace" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select A Marketplace</option>
                        <option>Ebay & Amazon</option>
                        <option>Ebay</option>
                        <option>Amazon</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <img class="marketPlaces" ng-src="{{image}}" />
                        <img class="marketPlaces" ng-show=" showImg" ng-src="{{imageSecond}}" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="content">
                        <rzslider rz-slider-model="minRangeSlider.minValue" rz-slider-high="minRangeSlider.maxValue" rz-slider-options="minRangeSlider.options"></rzslider>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="search">Min Price</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="minTextVal" id="slider-margin-value-min" readonly>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="search">Max Price</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="maxTextVal" id="slider-margin-value-max" readonly>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <label for="search">Prices High To low</label>
                    <input id="highToLowBox" type="radio" ng-value="true" ng-model="priceOrder">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <label for="search">Prices Low To high</label>
                    <input id="lowToHighBox" type="radio" ng-value="false" ng-model="priceOrder">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" ladda="searchingService.updating" type="submit" data-style="zoom-in" style="width:100%">
                        <span>Update</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="canvas" id="resultsView">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <button id="menuBtn" type="button" ng-click="ScrollUp()" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-recalc="false" data-target=".navmenu" data-canvas=".canvas">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="containerId" class="container">
            <div class="topOffSet ">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <div id="itemHolder">
                        <h4><b>{{searchingService.searchList.length}} Results found from your search criteria.</b></h4>
                        <div class="panel panel-default col-lg-12 text-center" ng-show="searchingService.noResults">
                            <div class="panel-body"><img src="Images/CompzeeLogoSmall.png" class="logoSize" /><p>We could not find any results to match your search criteria</p><p>Please review your search terms and try again.</p></div>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-repeat="item in searchingService.filteredItems" class="col-lg-4">
                            <div class="panel panel-default maxPanelHeight">
                                <div class="panel-heading textOverflow" id="panelHeading">
                                    <h3 class="panel-title text-center"><b>{{item.Title}}</b></h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <a href={{item.url}} target="_blank"><img src={{item.Image}} class="picHeight img-rounded img-responsive center-block" /></a>
                                    <h4 class="text-center"><b>{{item.Price}}</b></h4>
                                    <h4 class="text-center"><a href={{item.url}} class="btn btn-success" target="_blank">See More</a></h4>
                                    <div class="text-center"><img class="originPic" src={{item.marketPlaceImg}} /></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <uib-pagination total-items="items.length" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-md" boundary-links="true" rotate="false">
                </uib-pagination>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have created the example Can you replicate your issue in this link [codepen](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/VKwOgz?editors=1100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you have z-index issue:**

1. add z-index: 1000; to the .navmenu class.
2. if still doesn't show it at top, add z-index: 1; to the .canvas class.
3. if still doesn't work, it means you are using z-index inside other classes (sub or parent tags of .canvas or .navmenu class). for solving it you need to remove them. for searching it you just search z-index inside your entire project to find which one causing problem and then try number 1 and 2 again. Please be aware of inline styles. don't search just inside your css file. (I don't know what is your IDE but if you are using Eclipse just press CTRL+H and type z-index to search your entire project)
4. if you did 1,2 and 3 and still doesn't work, it means you cached and need to clear your cache.

**If you have Height Issue:**

Put Height:100%; where you wrote overflow-x:hidden. Height 100% means 100% of parent height. When you put height:100% inside a node which it's parent has 200px height. it means node height will be 200px and not more.

Answer (score 0):

Use the z-index property to show an element above an other.

The bigger z-index will be up the others.

Exemple: z-index:2 will be shown up to z-index:1.

Comment: This isn't always true. You should read about the [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).